# Find rational notation for $4.\overline{125}$ using the concept of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, rational-numbers

> Find rational notation for $4.\overline{125}$ using the concept of a series.

I know how to find rational notation using the cheap trick called putting the repeating digits over $9$'s, getting $\dfrac{4121}{999}$, but how can I do it using the concept of an infinite geometric series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

$$4.\overline{125} = 4 + 0.125 + 0.000125 + 0.000000125 + \ldots\\
= 4 + \frac{125}{1000} + \frac{125}{1000^2} + \frac{125}{1000^3} + \ldots$$

And now you can factor out $\frac{125}{1000}$ and apply what you know about $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^k$.

Comment: After factoring out $\frac{125}{1000}$ I get $\frac{125}{1000}(32+1+\frac1{1000}+\frac1{1000^2}+\frac1{1000^3}\dots)$. This is not a geometric sequence...

Comment: @suomynonA Separate 4. Only factor those on fractions

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Got it, thanks

Comment: @suomynonA You're welcome.--)